# creating a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I would like to creat a batch file that will recognise folders date moidified in a network drive and then copy them to another network drive
while I was searching I found way to do that to files, but I need it for folders
I didn't find a way to do that

Comment: [How to Write a Batch File (with examples)](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you didn't say which method you'd found. If that method selects the files using a `DIR.../a-d...` structure for instance, then omit the `-` before the `d` and directories matching the selected pattern rather than files would be processed.

Answer (score 0):

To create a batch file just get notepad++ and save as a .bat, is that what you meant? or did you want a certain type of Batch file, because I didn't think there was another type unless you count Command prompt and Notepad++ different?

Answer (score 0):

`Forfiles` may be helpful, or `robocopy`

This will create a mirror backup in the destination folder.  If files are deleted in the source then they will also be deleted in the destination.

```
@echo off
robocopy "\\172.172.172.10\folder" "\\172.172.172.2\destination" /mir
```